# NoMethodError: undefined method `users' within a setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

maybe is a dumb question, but I am having an issue when I am trying to run a test on Ruby, this is the error:

> Error: UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `User' for #UsersLoginTest:0x0000555ef3ec15b0 Did you mean?  super
> test/integration/users_login_test.rb:6:in `setup'

I tried to fix the fixture .yml but I am not sure that the problem is there anymore.

This is my users.yml

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

this is my users_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end
  
  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                          password: 'password' } }
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

and this is my test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  setup do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end
  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end
  
end
```

where could be the problem? thank you very much for your help

**New Attachments**

irb(main):002:0> User.column_names

=> ["id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest"]

I tried changing password_digest: 123456, but it throws the same error.
I tried changing to password: test_password, and this comes up:

> UserTest#test_should_be_valid:
>
> ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no columns
> named "password".

Also I am attaching my gem file, where the only file I intentional used to authentication was gem 'bcrypt' I think:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'


gem 'rails', '6.0.1'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '9.6.1.1'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '5.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.5'
gem 'mini_magick', '4.9.5'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.4.1'
gem 'puma', '4.3.1'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.7.0.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '6'
gem 'webpacker', '4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '5'
gem 'jbuilder', '2.9.1'
gem 'rubocop', '0.77.0'
gem 'bootsnap', '1.4.2', require: false
gem 'rails-controller-testing'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.12'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.1'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '3.2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',           '3.28.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '3.142.4'
  gem 'webdrivers',         '4.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'
  # gem 'fog', '1.42'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And just in case I created a repository: https://github.com/cochabambinoski/Share-Exercise

Comment: Not sure why you have a setup and a test in your test_helper.rb.

Comment: Is the problem possibly in your Fixture? Fixtures get loaded into the DB on start of the test. Try putting a `password: fake_password` into the fixture instead of that ERB. It is failing on that `User...` call in the fixture.

Comment: @Beartech Hi, I already tried the password thing, but nothing changed, same error. I am attaching the DB Table info

Comment: That's not helpful, but if you can add the code that you tried to your question and let us know that it resulted in the exact same error (or a slightly different one) that is helpful. That is why they ask you to put any troubleshooting you've already done, in your question, so we don't waste our time asking you to do it.

Comment: @Beartech Yes, exactly the same code issue

Comment: But you said "I did that". If you did what I recommended you shouldn't have gotten the same error because I'm not using the `User.` constant.

Comment: Also you need to include what ever gem you are using for User authentication.

Comment: And remove all of the `setup do...` and `test.. ` from the test_helper.rb. You have too many things going on that could be conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is you set up `test_helper.rb` as a test itself and that is causing you problems. Your file should look like:

```
#test_helper.rb
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase #you were creating a new class in your code
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

end
```

That's it, all I had to do after cloning your repo was to bundle install, and do a `rake db:create` and `rake db:test:prepare`. Now the test passes. Don't forget to change your fixture back to:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Big lesson here is `test_helper.rb` is a place for some configuration and settings, not the place to put tests.

Comment: I couldnt fix it, so I am uploading the project, just in case

Comment: wow, you are amazing man, like the real God of Ruby, you have an answer for everything :D, but it is a little weird, I tried that, I cleaned up test_helper.rb just like you said in an old comment, but it didn't work for me. Anyways, thank you very much, you are the best :)

Comment: One thing you will really help yourself by learning is WHY `class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase` is not working and `class  ActiveSupport::TestCase`  does. The first one is creating an NEW class that inherits from `ActiveSupport::TestCase` and IF you had created new tests that inherited via `class SomeTest < UserTest` it would have inherited from UserTest AND it's parent ActiveSupport::TestCase. The way I've shown you instead of creating a new class you are simply adding to ActiveSupport::TestCase.